# laravel - query builder cross join sub query

Tags: mysql, laravel

I made a sql query and want to build it in laravel with the builder,

I made use of a cross join on a sub query to get all the amount of rows between 2 dates, if it matches it will fill in the data else fill it with null.

SQL:

```
select 
    username,
    date_gen as date,
    skill_exp.*
from users cross join (
SELECT
    date_gen
from (
    select DATE_ADD(curdate() - INTERVAL 10 DAY, INTERVAL (@i:=@i+1)-1 DAY) as `date_gen`
    from information_schema.columns,(SELECT @i:=0) gen_sub 
    where DATE_ADD(curdate() - INTERVAL 10 DAY,INTERVAL @i DAY) BETWEEN curdate() - INTERVAL 10 DAY AND curdate()
    ) date_generator
) date_gen
left join skill_exp on users.id = skill_exp.user_id and date_gen.date_gen = skill_exp.date
where username = 'thebloodeyes'
```

How would I be able to make the sub part in laravel so i can use it on the left join to skill_exp

sub query part:

```
SELECT
    date_gen
from (
    select DATE_ADD(curdate() - INTERVAL 10 DAY, INTERVAL (@i:=@i+1)-1 DAY) as `date_gen`
    from information_schema.columns,(SELECT @i:=0) gen_sub 
    where DATE_ADD(curdate() - INTERVAL 10 DAY,INTERVAL @i DAY) BETWEEN curdate() - INTERVAL 10 DAY AND curdate()
) date_generator;
```

Outcome sub query:
[image]
Outcome total query:
[image]

Comment: *"I made a sql query and want to build it in laravel with the builder,"* Great the easy way around it would be to make a VIEW in MySQL and query/use that instead from laravel..  But that would most likely not scale well on the large to very large tables as that `GROUP BY` would force MySQL to handle that VIEW  to run as [internal temporary table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/internal-temporary-tables.html) instead of [merging](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/view-algorithms.html)

Comment: .. also this `GROUP BY` seams to be misused here to "unduplicate" those generated dates... And what i understand from that SQL part duplicated dates can never happen..  So that `GROUP BY` part is pretty much unneeded here..  Also i would phrase it as [this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c61cdb/22) instead of using  `information_schema.columns` then you have better control about the max number of records which the number generator generates and joins with..

Comment: ... also `information_schema.columns` can trigger some (random) disk I/O (4 ms - 10 ms delay per table) too open up the metafiles of all existing tables if the `information_schema.columns` cache somehow has become invalid and needs to be refreshed..

Comment: *"I made a sql query and want to build it in laravel with the builder,"* Back to topic: it should be in the [Database: Query Builder laraval manual](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries)  you need to look into the **"Advanced Join Clauses/Sub-Query Joins"** in the [JOIN](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#joins) section to make those derived (subquery) table possible.. That other `DATE_ADD(curdate() - INTERVAL 10 DAY, INTERVAL (@i:=@i+1)` syntax for example could be as [Raw Expression](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#raw-expressions)

Comment: Thanks for the information, i'm trying to figure out how it all works at moment. looking how the SQL you sended is working. And with the Joins it expects that i do a on table.something =  other.something, how do i work around that i could not be able to find

Comment: Might it be better to get the available data from the database and check with php wich dates are missing and add a null value in that date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I left out that the database will handle the missing dates and moved it to php.
Let me know if there are some mistakes or that handling this in database would be more preferable

Executing time: 0.035382032394409ms~
Request time to api: 105ms~

Start date: 2013-06-01
End date: 2025-07-01
Database dates total: 1, 2018-10-21

```
        $user = User::with(['exp' => function ($query) {
            $query->whereDate('date', '>=', '2018-10-21');
        }])
            ->where('username', '=', $id)
            ->firstOrFail();


        return Helper::addMissingDates("2013-06-01", "2025-07-01", $user->exp);
```

addMissingDates function:

```
    public static function addMissingDates($dateStart, $dateEnd, $expTables) {
        $newExpTable = [];
        $begin = new DateTime( $dateStart );
        $end = new DateTime($dateEnd);
        $end = $end->modify( '+1 day' );

        $interval = new DateInterval('P1D');
        $daterange = new DatePeriod($begin, $interval ,$end);

        foreach($daterange as $date) {
            foreach ($expTables as $expTable) {
                if($date->format("Y-m-d") === $expTable->date) {
                    $newExpTable[] = $expTable;
                    continue 2;
                }
            }
            $exp = new \stdClass();
            $exp->found = false;
            $exp->date = $date->format("Y-m-d");
            $newExpTable[] = $exp;
        }


        return $newExpTable;
    }
```